# Vim: Visual Selection?

Tags: bash, centos, filesystems, vim, alias

[image]

Not sure why but lines 2-6 has white background.  How do I remove this?

the s in alias is what is making the white background come into play.  Not sure how to remove this.

Comment: If you press the `Escape` key just after the white background appears, does it remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Visual mode :

You probably are in visual-block mode, used for rectangular selection.
You probably pressed `Ctrl+v` (or quadruple click) by accident.
There are also a visual-line mode with `Shift+v`, or visual mode with `v`.

Simply press the `Escape` key if you want to go back to normal mode.

You can also perform different actions, for example,
yank (copy) the selected area with `y`, or delete it with `d`.

To learn more about visual modes, you can use Vim's documentation with `:h visual.txt`.

### If it's not visual mode :

Your screenshot really looks like visual-block mode, but maybe it's something else (press the `Escape` key when you see white background. If white background disappears, it was visual mode. Else, it comes from another Vim's feature).

There can be several reasons why some text appears in a different color or background color like:

- If you customized the syntax highlighting (run the command `:syntax off`,
  or simply `:syn off`, and if the white background disappears, it was syntax-related. If it does not works, and you want to have colored text again, `:syn on` will do that).
- If you searched (usually with `/` or `?`, but it can appear with other commands like `:%s/foo/bar/`) the word `alias` previously and you told Vim to highlight `Search` in white (run the command `:nohlsearch`, or symply `:noh`, and if the white background disappears, it was search-related).
- If you ran the `:match […]` command, it can highlight the text too, but this command is less used than searches using `/` (run the command `:match` with no argument to remove the current matched pattern, and if the white background disappears, it was match-related).
- If you use some color-related plugins like `quickhl`, it may do this (so, "I don't know", it depends on the plugins you use).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I looked at the documentation.  When I remove the space between a and s the white background comes into play. no clue how to remove this.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the space between a and s"? How did you remove it? What do you mean by "play"?

Comment: when I move the cursor after the a I press the space bar and alia goes teal space s but when I remove the space the text goes back to white background.

Comment: I am not sure I perfectly understand (what does the word "teal" mean? for example).

Comment: Also, when you have white background (actually, visual mode), do you see the text `-- VISUAL BLOCK --` on the bottom/status line? If you don't, then, run the command `:set smd` to see it. With this, you will always know if you are in a visual mode or not (sometimes, if you only selected 1 char, you will not see any white background but you will still be in a visual mode).

Comment: I am not in visual-line mode.  I press escape and the white background does not disappear so the white background is coming from another vim feature.  
I changes to ":syn off" and the white background was still there.
Boom! ":noh" was the answer

I do not see -- VISUAL BLOCK -- on the bottom status line.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your feedback. If `:noh` works, it means the word `alias` was searched previously.  BTW, if someday you want to change the search color, you can do `:hi Search ctermfg=0 ctermbg=11` (with my example, it's yellow background with black text, but you can do any combination of the [256 colors](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/) you want). And if you want words like ":syn off" to appears with a grey background on Stackexchange:  `:syn off`, it can be done with ` `backsticks` `